Why do I get the error "No audio header found within ...mp3."?
I am working on a music player and, let's say I want to change the album name of a specific song with the use of jaudiotagger:
AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(new File("file.mp3"));
Tag tag = audioFile.getTag();
if (tag != null) {
  tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, "Album2024");
  audioFile.commit();
}

But no matter which file I try, I always get the error:

No audio header found within file.mp3.


And you're sure .getPath() includes file file's name at all?

Yes, everything is included there, from /storage to ...mp3.

And how do you confirm it is in MP3 format (and not something different just being name .mp3)? Include its first 20 bytes into your question. Or already check yourself against potential starting bytes of MP3 and others, like MP4, OGG, WMA....

Well I know, that all my files in this folder are of the format .mp3.

That still woudn't answer which software can deal with it which doesn't - hence as an indicator their first 20 bytes please. Just because you can play them back with software X doesn't mean library Y is able to deal with exactly that file - it could still carry unexpected/wrong metadata. Linking same Q - what's the exception name you get?

Just try to parse the file with editor like 010 editor, or you may just parse it yourself with hex editor. It would not have correct mp3 format header.

Regular MP3 files don't have a place for tags.  They're just streams of MPEG frame after MPEG frame.
Most folks tagging MP3s will use ID3 v1 or ID3 v2 tags.
So, it's possible/likely that your tagging software is correct, and you need to figure out how to add an ID3 tag before you can add metadata to it.

Most of this isn't wrong (the rest guesswork), but none of it helps one tiny bit. I've even linked to the library's source by editing the Q, which you could have investigated. Also "no audio header" indicates an MPEG frame's header is meant, not a (missing) ID3 tag.
